# Access File Stored in the Root Directory (as opposed to being a child of public_html)

Tags: python, cgi, public-html

How do I access file/scripts stored in a subfolder of my root folder from something in a site directory (e.g. access `/python/test.py` from `public_html/site1/cgi-bin/example.py`)?

Comment: You should be able to access it as `/python/test.py` assuming you've set the permissions for that path such that your webserver can access it, unless your webserver has called [`chroot(2)`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/chroot), in which case you can't.

Comment: @Aya `/` returns me the root path of the site (e.g. `public_html/site1`).

Comment: Sounds like your webserver is `chroot`ed then, so you won't be access anything outside `public_html/site1`. If it's your webserver, you can reconfigure it to not do the `chroot`, but if you don't have administrative access, you'll have to ensure all the files you want to access are inside `public_html/site1`.